# GIT Delete Repository and clone on local machine

Tags: git

I have a branch called  *master on the local machine

and I have three repositories called:

- /git/app
- /git/framework
- /git/site

On this local machine, there is a lot of problems with files, out of sync, etc. 
the decision has been made to just delete the /site directory and re -clone this from master. 
I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Wow, that is one confusing question.... Can you be more clear on the situation? What is `/site`, why are you referring to branch `master`, each repo has it's own set of branches, even if they are named the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want -

```
$ rm -fr /git/site
$ mkdir /git/site && cd /git/site
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/org/repo.git
$ git pull origin master
```

your `/git/site` will now be reset to your master branch.

Comment: The last 4 commands are equivalent to just doing a `git clone`, why make it more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: `:)` i get asked that question every day, and my response still remains the same.  `The more you understand the inner-workings of software, the better`

Comment: many people might not know that `git clone` does these commands "for" you.  it's nice to understand what the software is doing.

Comment: @wich same thing as `git pull` vs `git fetch origin, git merge origin/master`.  i prefer the second because i feel in control of what's happening, and i understand more how git works

Comment: ok I am a noob here, but this will not remove the branch / repository from the server, only the local workstation, correct?

Comment: that's correct. if you need to delete the branch remotely, do a 'git push --set upstream :mybranch'

Answer (score 3):

In general simply `rm -rf /my/git/repo` and then `git clone <wherever I want to clone from> /my/new/git/repo`